# java preparedstatement executeUpdate return wrong affected rows

Tags: java, spring, prepared-statement, jdbctemplate

I use spring jdbctemplate to update some rows,bute I got this log message.Two exact same sql returns different affected rows.There is no way the second update operation returns 0 affected rows.I just can't figure it out.

```
2015-12-03 12:37:37 [INFO] [qtp683362635-1187] c.t.s.c.i.d.IDGJdbcDao - update:

update JCSZ..T_IDG
   set N_VALUE = ?
 where C_BusinessID = ?
   and C_ComID = ?
   and C_RateID = ?
   and N_TYPE = ?
   and N_ConfType = ?
```

**affected rows:373 rows**

```
        2015-12-03 12:37:38 [INFO] [qtp683362635-746] c.t.s.c.i.d.IDGJdbcDao - update:
update JCSZ..T_IDG
   set N_VALUE = ?
 where C_BusinessID = ?
   and C_ComID = ?
   and C_RateID = ?
   and N_TYPE = ?
   and N_ConfType = ?
```

**affected rows:0 rows**

Comment: You are using those statements with the exact same arguments, right? You are exceting them directly after each other, maybe there is some trigger, that changes one of your columns from the `where` clause when `N_VALUE` is changes? Just a random guess...

Comment: Another guess, do you set the exact same value twice? Maybe this returns 0 because nothing changed the second time.

Comment: Have you try changing the order of the statments ?

Comment: Yes,the where condition is the same.I just choose some logs to show you guys the case.The real log says thousands of update operations,only a handful few of update returns o,they are all the same where conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some reserach (asking google) I found some hints on `UPDATE WITH RETURNING` only giving you the number of rows that actually changed. At leas this should be the behaviour for:

- [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-update.html)
- [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

I assume that it holds for other database systems as well.

Therefor your result is exactly what should happen, when executing the exact same update query twice. The first time everything is changed, returning you the number of rows that were found, and the second time nothing is changed anymore, giving you `0`.

Comment: The updating column is not in the where columns,so if does not take into account other factors, everytime I execute the sql,if where condition is the same,it should return the same result,Even if the results is diffirent,it should not be 0

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: `table`: {id: 1, value: 0}. `code`: `update table set value = 2 where id = 1; update table set value = 2 where id = 1`. The first update will return 1, because 1 row was changed from `0` to `2`. The second update sees `table_updated`: {id: 1, value 2} so it returns 0 because changing value from `2` to `2` is not affecting any row. If this is not what is happening in your case I missunderstood your question.

Comment: It's totally possible if there are some thread safety issues,then it would happen the case as you said.You are a true life saver